# Block display added for the view is repeating the content in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I have created a view to list the page content type(title, teaser and image).. and this view has a relationship with the image content type..
I have created a block display for above view and this block list the content depending on the reference between image and page content type (Page content type has CCK node reference field to set the relation between the page and image content).
This block in placed on the image content detail page and it list only those page content type that are associated with the current nodeID.
But this view is repeating the content (a page content is repeated multiple times and this repetition count is not fixed). One more point this block display view has a argument for NodeID which i have assigned as fixed argument and provided the arg(1) under PHP code.

Any help would be highly appreciated.... Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG.. i finally got the issue resolved.. the culprit was argument.. i had used the PHP code in argument and set its value to arg(1)... now i changed argument and set it to full from the URL... guess what the issue is resolved....

Anyways this answer will help newbie... and had teach me as well to use PHP code as last option...

Cheers Drupallers...